# How to attach layout/activitise to menu in Navigation Drawer Activity

Tags: android

Hi I am using Navigation Drawer Activity theme to create my Android application in Android studio. Tell me how to assign different layout/activity to Menu Item when clicked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is recommended that if your are using Navigation Drawer then you should use Fragments along with it, instead of using Activities.If you use Navigation Drawer with Activities then you will have to define the Navigation Drawer for each Activity.You can always use Fragment Manager to switch between Fragments.